# Can't target svg element with query selector

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a big svg file, that is displayed on an html page, with the following code

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0"
   width="680"
   height="520"
   viewBox="1754 161 9938 7945"
   id="svg2">
  <title
     id="title4">Countries of Europe</title>
  <desc
     id="desc6"> A blank Map of Europe. Every country has an id which is its ISO-3166-1-ALPHA2 code in lower case.
 Members of the EU have a class=&quot;eu&quot;, countries in europe (which I found turkey to be but russia not) have a class=&quot;europe&quot;.
 Certain countries are further subdivided the United Kingdom has gb-gbn for Great Britain and gb-nir for Northern Ireland. Russia is divided into ru-kgd for the Kaliningrad Oblast and ru-main for the Main body of Russia. There is the additional grouping #xb for the &quot;British Islands&quot; (the UK with its Crown Dependencies - Jersey, Guernsey and the Isle of Man) 
 ... file continues on
```

i have used this javascript code, to different sections of the svg code targeting their id using this code

```
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    const dir = (e.target.closest('g').id);
    alert(dir);
});
```

but i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f06ab605832628ed0f5f:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (html5-entities.js:190)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f06ab605832628ed0f5f:19)
at bootstrap f06ab605832628ed0f5f:62
at bootstrap f06ab605832628ed0f5f:62
```

whenever i click most of the parts, it will return another error:

```
(index):27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

but few parts of the drawing alerts the id of the element

Comment: Displayed on a html page how? Inline?

Comment: How can i make it target something out of its id? Should i upload the file?

Comment: @Robert Longson yes

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Also, one thing to check: It won't work if your JavaScript runs in your head section before the svg element is parsed later on in the document.

Comment: @Maximillian I'm running from a separate file

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Where in the HTML document are you putting the script tag for your JS file?

Comment: at the bottom @Maximillian, so the SVG renders first

Comment: @baileyhaldwin Your document structure must be the issue, as the query selector is working. I would suggest you add more of your code into the question, and maybe create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) https://jsfiddle.net/c8zsr5uh/